# TeamSpeak SDK on Android Using Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, teamspeak

I am trying to use TeamSpeak SDK on Android using Qt

1 - I link the .so file comes with TeamSpeak SDK to my Qt Project

2 - Release and APK file and setup it on my Android phone

It works fine, without a problem and connects to TeamSpeak server, but I can't open device Mic or Speaker. 
 When I try to use
`ts3client_getCaptureModeList` and `ts3client_getPlaybackModeList`
to see the available devices I can't find anything.

I face this problem on Windows when I don't add the soundbackends file that comes with TeamSpeak SDK. I think that TeamSpeak SDK should have a soundbackend for Android too.

What I'm trying to do is to take the soundbackends on Windows, add it to my Android phone, add the path to sound backends (which is /storage/emulated/0/) but it does not work.

The question is where can I get this files, or what I should do to make sound work?

Comment: Where did you get the soundbackends for windows from? and I doubt the ones from windows would work but if they is a linux version in the same location that might help since android uses the linux kernel.

Comment: first Thanks for your reply and sorry for  late i get soundbackends file from the TeamSpeak SDK folder that I download it from TS website and add tha path for the soundbackends file but not work ?